# Measure app start trace with Firebase Performance

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-performance

I have an app on React Native. I've integrated it with React Native Firebase library and particularly with Firebase Performance. Even by default it creates the trace to measure time for app start.

For example, now for Android it shows median time 319 ms. But in fact it takes several seconds to load. I suppose, it measures only time until all native code is ready, while I need to measure time until first React Native screen is ready. Can this be measured somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase performance measures the app_start using the methodology documented here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/automatic

You can create a custom trace to measure the time from the onResume() call until the react native screen is ready.